# SQL create data that doesn't exist

Tags: sql, ms-project-server-2010

This is specifically for Project Server if that helps.  PS only calculates capacity in the database for a max of 3 years out.  I have forecasts > 3 years out.

I need to pull data and see the capacity and forecasts for > 3 years and since the capacity doesn't exist, "create" it using 8*# of weekdays that month.  I have SQL for capacity and forecasts that works fine, I just can't figure out how to "create" the capacity if the data doesn't exist.

I have read other posts and seen similar questions but couldn't get an answer from them.  I have tried using not in and a few other things like is null for the capacity and forecast dates but not getting the right results.  Just looking for someone to help point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, then try this on the Server Settings page:

```
Operational Policies section
click Additional Server Settings
Resource Capacity Settings section
Active capacity view      
Months ahead field, enter value greater than 36
```

If not, please describe or add more specifics to your question.

Comment: Project Server only allows a max of 36 months to be set for capacity.  If you enter a value > 36 months, you get an error stating:  "The value of Months ahead must be from 0 through 36.".  I need to query capacity and forecasts > 36 months out and force the capacity > 36 months to be a calculation of 8 hours a day.

Comment: Yes, that's a limitation not in Project Server 2012. Sorry I didn't pay close attention to your server version.